# VB.net: read and write an .Net-Object with SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

What will I have to do when I want to read a `FileInfo` from a SQLite-database? The following code works fine and stores the field (the column in SQLite is blob):

```
com.Parameters.Add("@info", DbType.Object)

com.Parameters("@info").Value = New FileInfo(filename)
```

How can I read the result of a query (result is of course one `FileInfo`) into a `FileInfo` using the `SQLiteDataReader`?

The following code (`rd` represents the `DataReader`) produces an error:

> can't convert from byte() to FileInfo

```
Dim fi as FileInfo = DirectCast(rd.GetValue(0), FileInfo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `FileInfo` object to be stored as Binary/BLOB, it has to be converted to a byte array.  As far as I know, `SQLite` only knows how to do that for one thing, so you have to do it yourself using serialization:

```
Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
...
Using ms As New MemoryStream
    bf.Serialize(ms, fi)
    ms.Position = 0
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@f", DbType.Binary).Value = ms.ToArray
End Using
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You'll have to deserialize the result when reading it back.  Neither is very difficult, but it would be simpler to save the full filename and create a new `FileInfo` from that:

```
If rdr.Read Then
   n = rdr.GetString(0)
   fi = New FileInfo(n)
   ...
```